# Restoring SQL database After File lost

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have all backup files,full differential and transaction log,
suppose I have 10 transaction log backup files. if 4th file get deleted then how to restore remaining file.

Comment: Then you can restore full + diff + up to the 3rd log file if no full/differential backup was made after that 4th log backup

Answer (score 1):

A continuous sequence of Transaction Log backups are tied by a `Log Chain(Log Sequence Number)`, which starts with a FULL backup, unless you do something to break the LSN (TLog Backup with Truncate or change recovery mode etc), you will need to restore these backups in order, without breaking the Log Chain.

For example in your case you can do the following to restore to a point in time:

1. Restore Last Full Backup
2. Restore Last Differential Backup
3. Restore Log Backups taken after the Diff Backup in Order, without missing out any transaction log backups taken, else you will get an error like:

> The log in this backup set begins
> at LSN 7000000000001, which is too recent to apply to the database. An
> earlier log backup that includes LSN 7000000000000 can be restored.
>
> RESTORE LOG is terminating
> abnormally.

*Moral of the Story*

Unfortunately Transaction log backups must be restored in continuous order without missing out any backup files.

Comment: that means if i lost 4th file then further files are useless?

Comment: @vinGa yes unfortunately they are useless